# How does tensorflow deal with blank data values?

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, dataset

I have a dataset, saved as a csv, that I'm trying to create a regression model off of, but the dataset has several blank values (as shown in the image, for each row of data, there are values in some columns but not others). I'm planning on following this tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression), however I haven't used tensorflow before so I'm not sure if this can handle the blank data values.

If not is there any workaround? I was thinking of completely removing the rows that contain blank data, but I'm not sure how to go about that either. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

[image: This is what some of my data looks like]

Answer (score 0):

It is already mentioned in the same [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression#clean_the_data) you have shared.

You can simply load the csv file you have as below:

```
    import pandas as pd
    raw_dataset = pd.read_csv("full_path_of_csv_file.csv")
    dataset = raw_dataset.copy()    #To make a copy of your csv file to avoid changes in the existing file
    dataset.tail()                  #To check the last 5 rows of dataset or
    dataset.head()                  #To check the first 5 rows of the dataset
    dataset.isna().sum()            #To check if there are any NaN values in your dataset
    dataset = dataset.dropna()      #This will remove all the rows containing 0 values or missing values
```